# Unifying dynamic predicates in SWI Prolog

Tags: c++, swi-prolog

I am calling a SWI Prolog engine from a C++ dll and I would like to be able to access all asserted/dynamic predicates (similar to what listing normally does).

In GNU Prolog I would call the dynamic/1 predicate with a Variable and Prolog would unify it with all dynamic predicate indicators. In the next step I would call these predicates with variables and get a complete list.

Unfortunately I can't do that in SWI Prolog (ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated). 
Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just roll your own, for example:

```
get_dynamic_predicates(M, H, B, R) :-
    current_predicate(_, P),
    strip_module(P, M, H),
    predicate_property(P, dynamic), 
    \+ predicate_property(P, built_in), 
    \+ predicate_property(P, imported_from(_)),
    clause(P, B, R).
```

Calling this backtracks to bind instances of predicates with head `H` in module `M` with body `B` and clause reference `R`. If all you wanted to retrieve are the names of the dynamic predicates, you could call this to retrieve the set of all bindings for `H`, or the functors thereof.

Modify the predicate properties to those you'd prefer (or better yet, pass them in as arguments); the above definition will retrieve all user-defined dynamic predicates, which is what I'm guessing you're after.

Comment: Thanks. My latest idea was using something like this: 
    
myIndicators(Name, Arity) :-
        predicate_property(Head, dynamic),       
        \+ predicate_property(Head, built_in),     
        functor(Head, Name, Arity).

Comment: That's quite close to what I've suggested here; the only difference being I was making sure that dynamic predicates asserted in different modules were found. If you're not using multiple modules, then what you've suggested seems fine!